# injetar dependencia em uma função de link em uma directive angularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, front-end, angularjs-directives

Pessoal estou fazendo uma directive(componente) que necessita de uma dependência `$compile`, estou fazendo as operações no link da diretiva e preciso do `$compile` dentro dela só que não estou conseguindo injetar a dependência alguém ai já passou por algo parecido e conseguiu resolver?

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('calendar', ['calendar.tmpl'])
        .directive('calendar', calendar);

    function calendar() {
        var directive = {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                getData: '&',
                tipo: '@',
                iconSize: '@',
                modelo: '=',
                eventosData: '='
            },
            templateUrl: function (element, attrs) {
                if (attrs.tipo == 'calendar') {
                    return 'calendar.html';
                } else if (attrs.tipo == 'datapicker') {
                    return 'datapicker.html';
                }
            },
            link: linkFunc
        };

        return directive;
    }
    function linkFunc(scope){
  ***//quero injectar o $compile aqui***
   }
}());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Experimente fazer assim:

Você também pode tentar passar no: `calendar($compile) { ... }`
Caso não funcione, acredito que isso deve resolver o problema:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('calendar', ['calendar.tmpl'])
        .directive('calendar', ['$compile', function($compile) {

        var _scope = this,
        directive = {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                getData: '&',
                tipo: '@',
                iconSize: '@',
                modelo: '=',
                eventosData: '='
            },
            templateUrl: function (element, attrs) {
                if (attrs.tipo == 'calendar') {
                    return 'calendar.html';
                } else if (attrs.tipo == 'datapicker') {
                    return 'datapicker.html';
                }
            },
            link: _scope.linkFunc
        };

    return directive;

    this.linkFunc = function(scope){
      ***//quero injectar o $compile aqui***
    }

   }]);


}());
```